# msdeploy build with TeamCity - ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN

Tags: iis, teamcity, msdeploy

I've got a 2012R2 Continuous Integration Server with TeamCity installed on it and WebDeploy 3.5. I'm trying to deploy a build to a site which is hosted on another Server2012R2 using IIS 8.5 (it also has Web Deploy 3.5 installed) and I am getting this error message:

```
Error Code: ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN
[13:12:26][Step 3/3] More Information: Connected to 'myiisserver' using the Web Deployment Agent Service, but could not authorize. Make sure you are an administrator on 'myiisserver'.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN.
[13:12:26][Step 3/3] Error: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

As you can see from the error message I can connect to the server but It can't authenticate with the credentials that I'm specifying. This is the command I am using:

```
msdeploy -source:package='%PackageFile%' -dest:auto,computerName='http://%WebServer%/MSDeployAgentService',username="myiisserver\blibli",password="password",authtype="Basic",includeAcls='False' -verb:sync -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension -setParamFile:"%ParamFile%" -setParam:"IIS Web Application Name"="%IisSiteName%" -enableRule:DoNotDelete
```

The username I'm using is an admin on both machines and I'm using also specifying the right password.

Could you please throw any light at this guys? I have already lost 3 hours trying to sort out this issue...

Many thanks

Comment: Are the machines connected to a domain? Might be worth reading this - http://blog.huilaaja.net/2013/10/06/web-deploy-error-user-not-admin-msdeployagentservice/

Comment: @Evolve Software Ltd - they're not connected to any domain

Comment: @Evolve Software Ltd - I've also tried your sugestion and no joy...

Answer (score 0):

I sorted the issue just by removing the authtype="Basic" option out of the command.

Hope it helps someone else in the future.

Comment: I also had to do this, otherwise it won't work: https://blog.dotnetframework.org/2010/10/29/401-not-authorized-for-msdeploy%E2%80%8F-msdeployagentservice/